# Is there a way to have multiple tags mentioned for one server in Ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

In ansible I have seen inventory file usage as below:

```
[somehostlist]
 hostname1
 hostname2
```

But is it possible to achieve below:

```
[hostlist1],[hostlist2]
 localhost1
 localhost2

[hostlist3],[hostlist4],[hostlist5]
 localhost3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can achieve it:

```
[hostlist1]
localhost1
localhost2

[hostlist2:children]
hostlist1

[hostlist3]
localhost3

[hostlist4:children]
hostlist3

[hostlist5:children]
hostlist3
```